# Error running Make commmand for Darknet in AWS Server

Tags: makefile, gpu, darknet

I am training a custom object detection model using Yolov3 and darknet. I initially started with google colab and now I exhausted the capacity on colab. Hence I migrated to AWS to access the GPU. While working in Colab, I had no major issues. The make command worked perfectly, but now when I try to resume the training of the model on the AWS server, I am getting an error building the darknet
I have modified the Makefile as:

```
GPU = 1
CUDNN = 1
OpenCV = 1
```

When I set GPU=0,it works fine, but when I set GPU=1, I get the following error. Please find the attached screenshot.

After reading other blogs, I even downgraded the CUDA version from 10.0 to 8.0.

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Please click on this below link to find the screenshot of the error.
[AWS-Makefile-Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRq3p.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was mismatch of CUDA version with darknet. After upgrading to the latest version - CUDA 11.3, my problem was solved!